# Slovak Passport Renewal in Australia

Tags: passports

I'm an Australian PR (Permanent Resident). My passport from my birth country is about to expire. While we are still in lockdown in Victoria and cannot travel anywhere, I cannot travel to our embassy in Canberra either.

What is another way, by which I can have my passport renewed?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the Slovak consulate to ask?  They might for instance have a process to renew by mail.